# ActionController::ParameterMissing in TagsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, destroy

I am attempting to trigger a destroy action from an index page for tags attached to multiple records. However, when the action is triggered I get the above error in the create action. The error does not occur when the create action is invoked. My code is as seen below.

Tag Controller

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_search

def new
    @tag = Tag.new
end

def create
    tag = Tag.create(tag_params)
    if tag.save
        redirect_to tags_path
    else
        redirect_to sign_up_path
    end
end

def destroy
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
    @tag.destroy

    redirect_to tags_path
end

private
    def tag_params
        params.require(:tag).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :recipes do
    resources :ingredients, :steps
    put :favorite, on: :member
  end

  resources :users

  get 'recipes' => 'recipes#index'
  get 'recipes/:id' => 'recipes#show'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'

  get 'tags' => 'tags#index'
  get 'new_tags' => 'tags#new'
  post 'tags' => 'tags#create'
  delete 'tags' => 'tags#destroy'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  root 'recipes#index'

end
```

Index

```
  <%= link_to 'New Tag', new_tags_path(@tag) %> 

  <% Tag.find_each do |tag| %>
    <%= tag.name %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete Tag', @tag,
              method: :destroy,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stemmed from a combination of issues in the Link To statement in the view. The Link as it should be written is below...

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Tag', tag_path(tag),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This route:

```
delete 'tags' => 'tags#destroy'
```

means "/tags" with no id parameter.

You have to tell the router that you want a part of the url used as the `:tag_id`

```
delete 'tags/:tag_id' => 'tags#destroy'
```

Anyway, I'd recommend you to stick with rails conventions and just use

```
resources :tags
```

and on the controller

```
@tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
```

I'm not sure why are you setting the routes manually, if you are new to Rails read this link: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You even have this lines

```
get 'recipes' => 'recipes#index'
get 'recipes/:id' => 'recipes#show'
```

which are unnecessary since `resources :recipes` already creates them.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggest above however I am still receiving the following error... ActionController::ParameterMissing in TagsController#create param is missing or the value is empty: tag

Comment: Can you show the log when you do the destroy request? I don't understand why you are getting an error on the create action.

Comment: Started POST "/tags" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-10 20:07:14 -0600
Processing by TagsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"4OWmSZoqtiZHeTPnVEdawCLF3aVpRcYDkXgoMDElNPX/rDw2YxXvdJM+fMMpyUuBDLRVpv3HaFtGSftQsI/FsQ=="}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: tag):

app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:27:in `tag_params'
app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Comment: It looks like for some reason the destroy action is running the create instead?

Comment: do you have the rails-ujs gem installed? by default a `link_to` can't do a request with DELETE method, rails uses rails-ujs to handle that https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-method

Comment: I think you don't need a gem, but you need this line on the application.js manifest `//= require rails-ujs`